# How can I interpolate a variable from a command line argument into a string?

Tags: perl

My program takes a command line argument which I would like to use to change the working directory of my Perl script.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std; 
use Cwd 'chir';

my %opts=(); 
getopts('a:v:l:', \%opts); 
my $application = $opts{a}; 
my $version = $opts{v}; 
my $location = $opts{l}; 

print "$application, $version, $location\n"; 

if($application eq 'abc') {
    #print "you came here\n"; 
    chdir "/viewstore/ccwww/dst_${application}_${version}/abc/${location}";
    print $ENV{PWD}; 
    print "you came here\n"; 
}
```

I've previously tried with `chdir '/var/tmp/dst_$application/$version/$location';`, but that did not work either.

The current version of the code gives this warning.

> Global symbol "$application_" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20. Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Line 20 is the one with `chdir`.

Comment: i have tried like

Comment: use Getopt::Std; 

my %opts=();

 getopts('a:v:l: \%opts);
  
 my $application = $opts{a};
 my $version = $opts{v};
 my $location = $opts{l}; 
 
 if($application eq 'abc')
 
{
  chdir '/var/tmp/dst_$application/$version/$location';
}

Comment: i am getting exception near dst_$application as concentation error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stuff you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes `''` in your `chdir` command. Single quotes do not do variable interpolation in Perl. That means that `'/var/tmp/dst_$application/...'` means `/var/tmp/dst_$application/...`, and not `/var/tmp/dst_foo/...`.

You need to use double quotes `""` to interpolate variables in strings.

```
chdir "/var/tmp/dst_$application/$version/$location";
```

This will create `/var/tmp/dst_foo/...` instead.

If you need to separate a variable from the rest of the string, use this notation.

```
print "${foo}bar";
```

This is different from `"$foobar"` because Perl thinks the whole `$foobar` is the variable name.

Comment: i have tried double quotes but the values are not getting replaced in the script, Those variables I am updating from command line arguments

Comment: @mahesh please update your question with the code you have now.

Comment: use strict;
      4 use warnings;
      5
      6 use Getopt::Std;
      7
      8 my %opts=();
      9    getopts('a:v:l:', \%opts);
     10 my $application = $opts{a};
     11 my $version = $opts{v};
     12 my $location = $opts{l};
     13
     14 print "$application, $version, $location\n";
     15
     16 if($application eq 'abc')
     17
     18 {
     19 #print "you came here\n";
     20 chdir "/viewstore/ccwww/dst_$application_$version/abc/$location";
     21 print "you came here\n";
     22 }

Comment: Global symbol "$application_" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @mahesh you made a lot of effort to put the line numbers there. Why don't you just edit your question?!

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd 'chdir';

use Getopt::Std;

my %opts=();
   getopts('a:v:l:', \%opts);
my $application = $opts{a};
my $version = $opts{v};
my $location = $opts{l};

print "$application, $version, $location\n";

if($application eq 'abc')
{
#print "you came here\n";
chdir "/viewstore/ccwww/dst_$application_$version/abc/$location";
print $ENV{PWD};
}

Comment: i tried to add the same in question, but some how stackoverflow was not accepting my question

Comment: @mahesh Stack Overflow does not allow you to post additional questions because this question was so badly received. You don't need to add a new question. You need to EDIT the existing one. I posted a comment on the question with a link to the edit form. You can read all about editing [https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/202151](here). However, I've updated my answer and included the solution already. If that solves your problem, please read [ask] and then mark an answer as accepted. That will also help lift your question ban. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for prompt response, But when i try to edit the question i am getting exception you code not properly formatted. I have tried all the ways to post my code. I am unable to Find your solutions

Comment: @mahesh I've edited your question for you. Look at how I did the formatting to see what you did wrong. You need to do use `"dst_${application}_${version}`.

Comment: Thanks a ton i got it, I have another question when we are using chdir in the perl script after running the command I am returning to the current location where i am running the script. How to stay in the change directory

Comment: @mahesh I don't know. Please ask a new question for that. If you can't do that yet, you will need wait until the ban is lifted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/202151 for details about that. In the meantime, I believe accepting this answer would be a good start, if you feel it helped you. (I hate coercing people to accept my answers, this is just a suggestion).